# Htc one wifi download speed is slower then upload speed

Tags: wi-fi, htc, htc-one

I just bought a HTC one (m7) today and its working fine! But for some reason my wifi speed is really really slow on this phone. My download speed is slower then my upload speed at the moment wich isnt normal I think. This doesnt happen on other phones/laptops in this wifi network.

Why is the wifi download speed so slow on my HTC one? It started while downloading the newer updates it took hours to download/install them. After that the wifi is still really slow. 
I tried a speedtest from speedtest.net and came out with a weird result:

1 Mbps download
5 Mbps upload

On my laptop connected to same wifi network:

40 Mbps download
5 Mbps upload

So the upload speed is fine but for some reason i only get 1 mbps download speed wich should be 40.

What is causing this and whats the best way to solve this?

Thanks for reading/help.

Router: Technicolor TG789vn v3

Phone: HTC One (m7 black)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! :-)

If you also have this problem you have to change your router security from wpa2-psk to wpa. This worked for me on a technicolor router!

Google for your own router how to change this.